Can I assume a horizontal vector is a horizontal lift?
I am reading a proof that the curvature 2-form is given by $(F_A)_p(v,w) = dA_p(v,w) + [A_p(v),A_p(w)]$ where $A\in \Omega^1(P;\mathfrak{g})$ is a connection 1-form on $P\xrightarrow{\pi}M$.
One of the steps requires that we show that if $v\in H_pP$ is horizontal and $w\in V_pP$ is vertical, then $dA_p(v,w) = 0$, and I happen to know that $[X^H,Y] = 0$ if $X^H\in \Gamma(TP)$ is the horizontal lift of a vector field on $M$.
The proof says "We may assume that $v = X^H(p)$" for some $X\in \Gamma(TM)$, but I am extremely dubious of this claim.
I believe that I can construct a vector field whose value at $p$ is $v$ (by using a bump function or something I guess) and I even believe that I can construct a horizontal one. But I am positive that not every horizontal vector field is a horizontal lift
(see e.g. the counterexample here:  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Not_Every_Horizontal_Vector_Field_is_Horizontal_Lift)
So is there a reason I can assume $v = X^H(p)$ $\exists X\in \Gamma(TM)$ in this case?

At the level of vector fields, the statement is not true. But if you’re working at one point, and you have one horizontal vector over that point, then yes you can find a vector field which is a horizontal lift and agrees with that vector at that point.

The way this works is of course simple: take your horizontal vector $v$, then project to the base to get $x$. Using a chart, you can find a local vector field which takes on the value $x$; then using a bump function you can extend the domain to the whole manifold, while still keeping the value $x$ at that point. Call this vector field $X$. Now take the horizontal lift $X^H$.
